# Comparing Averages Puzzle - Is This Government Agency Incorrect, Or Am I?

Tags: javascript, math, finance

I'm building a finance app in Javascript that averages prices...

For the year 2012, a large Government Agency has published hourly price data for every hour of the day (24).  My app took their hourly price data, and created Daily Averages for every day in 2012...

My Daily Averages matched the Daily Averages produced by the Government Agency for every day in 2012, which was great.  But then I used my Daily Averages to create Monthly Averages, and my Monthly Averages did not match the Monthly Averages produced by the Government Agency for 3 months in 2012: March, April and November.  The other 9 months match...

Here are the different averages:

```
March    -  Gov: $51.08  MyApp: $51.04
April    -  Gov: $41.69  MyApp: $41.7
November -  Gov: $87.41  MyApp: $87.48
```

Here are arrays of the Daily Averages for each month:

```
var march = [483.88,178.01,21.42,18.08,23.67,44.13,26.64,19.76,33.93,26.79,19.56,23.84,31.51,30.14,35.42,17.22,25.95,20.64,45.61,42.69,28.84,43.84,89.11,69.07,24.88,29.38,19.59,38.47,33.66,14.25,22.26]

var april = [11.57,15.50,16.26,21.26,16.49,13.89,12.87,16.27,31.49,69.24,425.51,22.92,23.37,35.34,70.47,114.23,97.72,32.42,16.47,15.39,20.26,17.25,20.54,12.94,15.41,17.16,14.44,18.84,16.84,18.49]

var november = [38.47,50.14,31.97,34.24,29.43,87.62,133.99,166.51,59.79,41.96,32.81,21.22,26.92,42.27,29.74,45.26,157.18,78.12,31.09,178.70,273.16,186.90,28.27,68.48,90.05,117.13,27.04,115.14,108.06,292.88]
```

I create my averages by first having all prices as integers and not floating point using `.replace(/\./g,'')` to strip the periods and then running them through this code:

```
// Sum Up Daily Averages
   for(var x = 0; x < prices.length; x ++) {
      priceSum   = priceSum + prices[x]; 
   };
// Find Average
   priceAverage = Math.round(priceSum / poolprices.length);
```

I believe my averages are correct.  If so, how is the Government Agency arriving at those averages?  I thought it might be time change issues...  However, our Daily Averages all match, and there aren't 3 separate time changes in 3 months.  If my averages are incorrect, could it be Javascript doing something sneaky?  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered most (all?) governments lie - they love the illusion that most people do not give a toss

Comment: Absolutely.  But, I make mistakes every day, so that is where I'm going to start.

Comment: It seems April's average is matching (considering only 2 decimal digit and truncating anything beyond two digit). For March and November try to calculate monthly average directly from hourly data (chances are there that you get a match).

Comment: Kaushal, what would be the difference if I calculate directly from the hourly data?  I'll try it right now just in case...

Comment: Kaushal, I just tested for the month of March, and you're correct.  The average matched the Government's.  Do you know why that is the case?  What's the difference between averaging averages, and averaging the original numbers?

Comment: April could be a different rounding convention. In school we are told to always round 0.5 up. A more sophisticated version is to "round half even" so 0.5 rounds down, 1.5 rounds up, this has better statistical properties.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is likely due to rounding: If you do daily averages, round them, and from these rounded daily averages compute monthly averages, then you will likely get a different result than when you directly compute the average without rounding intermediate results.